# Upper-bounding $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = i}^{i+a_i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, asymptotics, approximation

Suppose $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ are arbitrary integers. Is it possible to bound 
$$
A =\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = i}^{i+a_i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}
$$
with either of the following: 
$$
B = c\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
$$
$$
C = c'\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{i}}
$$

for some arbitrary constants $c$, $c'$.

PS. I know that $\sum_{i=m}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \leq 2 (\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{m})$, but not sure it is useful. The only thing I can get is: 
$$
A \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2\sqrt{a_i + i} - 2\sqrt{i} = O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{a_i } \right)
$$

Also using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774740/is-it-true-that-sum-i-1m-frac1-sqrti-o-left-sqrt-m-1-right?noredirect=1#comment3622200_1774740) we know that 
$$
\sum_{j = i}^{i+a_i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} = O \left( \sqrt{ \frac{d_i}{i} } \right) \Rightarrow A = O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{ \frac{ a_i }{i}} \right)
$$

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with power-series or approximation-theory.